# jQuery bound window events and AJAX content

Tags: jquery, ajax, bind

I have a bit of jQuery that binds an orientation event to the page that, upon orientation change, removes a bunch of objects from the page:

```
$(window).bind('orientationchange',function(event){
    $('.tooltip-popup').remove();
})
```

This works. Upon orientation change, any object with that class is removed from the DOM.

However, if we then load more of those objects via AJAX, those items don't get removed on orientation change.

This is confusing as it was my assumption that upon orientation change, the DOM is re-queried to find said elements, so should find all elements, regardless of whether they were loaded via AJAX or not.

Is my assumption incorrect and that the DOM is queried on initial page load and, therefore, would never know about the objects loaded via AJAX unless I instead use `delegate` to bind the event?

Using `delegate` is certainly easy enough, but I wanted to make sure I understood what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in the fact that your dom elements, being added dinamically, are not bound to the event. A possible solution is to use the `.live()` or, for more recent versions of jquery `.on()`

Comment: Well, that's my question. I understand that an event bound to an object that hasn't loaded yet would not work, but this event is bound to the window.